Stopping specific edit widgets from triggering re-draws in QGIS
Typing text in a form field triggers a screen re-draw for every character typed, this causes performance issues and crashes as I have complex symbology.
Turning off rendering solves the performance issues but some fields need to trigger a re-draw whilst others do not.
Is there any way to stop specific edit widgets from triggering re-draws?
Or at least short cut to toggle the render box?
